# Input -поставить таймер

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы инпут (поле для ввода)был активен до определённого числа (даты)?
Пример:
с 1 числа по 25 число активный, а с 26 числа по 1 число не активный

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type='text' id='time' disabled='disabled'>

<script>
var today_day = new Date().getDate()
if (today_day >= 1 && today_day <= 25) {
   document.getElementById('time').removeAttribute('disabled');
}
</script>
```

via: http://javascript.ru/Date

Comment: поставил ваш код..вот только у меня Input не активен, а сегодня 6 число..должен быть активным. В чём проблема, не скажите?

Comment: @lampa, интересное у тебя условие: `today_day < 1` :)
@Саня-Саня, условие поправь на правильное и всё заработает.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, @Саня-Саня что-то произошло, и я всё перепутал.
Обновил пост.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо почитать [документацию](http://js-help.net/text/array_date_math/date/rabota_data.php) по работа с датам в `javascript`.

Потом на событие `onload` у `<body>` повесить обработчик который будет у [нужного `input'a`](http://htmlweb.ru/java/forms.php) выставлять свойство `disabled`.

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно:

```
var now = new Date();
var input = document.getElementById('myInput'); 
if (now.getDate()>=1 && now.getDate()<=25) input.disabled = false; else input.disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал так, если важно учитывать месяц||год || что то еще кроме дня.

```
var t = document.getElementById("t");

var now = new Date();

var block = new Date(now) ;     
block.setDate(8);

var end_block = new Date(now);
end_block.setDate(10);

   if(block - now <= 0 && end_block - now >= 0) {

     t.disabled = true;

   }
```

Comment: Может быть это и правильно, но мой совет на будущее: никогда не делайте большего, чем просили. Вам с этого ничего не будет, кроме как потерянного времени + поддержка лишних функций.

Comment: >учитывать месяц||год

LOL)

Comment: @lampa, я потратил на код не более минуты, так что потерю такого времени я переживу, если было бы что то по сложней я бы не стал писать больше чем спрашивали;)

Comment: @Palmervan, ???

Comment: @cyber_ua ну это вы на этот код меньше минуты потратили) У вас кстати ошибка в операторе >+

Comment: Спасибо что уделяете время.
Есть ещё один вопрос, если вам не трудно...как всё это привязать к времени которое на сервере а не у пользователя в компьютере?...Надеюсь правильно сформулировал вопрос. спасибо.

Comment: вам нужно создать объект Date параметры передать при создании страницы http://learn.javascript.ru/datetime

Comment: Спасибо большое...постараюсь сделать

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то не могу добавить комментарий, поэтому пишу в ответе. Хотел сказать что всеми этими атрибутами типа disabled надо пользоваться осторожно и обязательно должна быть дополнительная проверка (желательно на сервере). Потому что очень лекго эти атрибуты отключить прямо на активной "живой" странице и ввести данные даже если текущая дата не позволяет.